# Is this simple login secure?

Tags: php, security

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] === "correct" ) {
echo "<h1 style='color:green'>Password is correct, you may enter!!!</h1>";
}else{
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] !== "correct") {
die('<h1 style="color:red">Password is ICORRECT, you may not enter!!!</h1>');
}else{  
echo "Enter Password:";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='password'>";
echo "<input type='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
die();
}}  
?>
```

Aside from someone accessing your webserver and looking at the password, is there any way anyone could access your site such as a hacker, and see "Password is correct, you may enter!!!" without actually knowing the password.

And also, we can exclude stuff like SSL attacks and stuff like that.

I just want to know, on the face of it, is this login secure?

Comment: ""correct"" is  the hard coded password?

Comment: `stuff like SSL attacks and stuff like that`  What about brute force or dictionary attacks, is that covered in "stuff like that"

Answer (score 2):

I vote no. Passwords should never be in codebase, especially if you are tracking code in git. Use environment variables or a database.

Here's a nice package I use a lot of environment variable loading:

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Also never commit your env file to your repo either. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think everything related to login credentials are posing a threat if you hard code them somewhere in your code. I would rather use a database such as `MySQL` with a md5 hashed password which nobody can decode.

A good approach would be to search the username and password in database and see if they match:

```
SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='username' AND password='password'
```

If the query returns something, then you have a match. If it doesn't then print an error message.

Comment: "md5 hashed password" please dont recommend such terrible practices

Comment: You're right, simple md5(password) is not recommended as my answer was vague. I was comparing a hard coded password with an md5. Salted passwords are always recommended.

Comment: PHP has added password functions in version 5.5 which can help prevent you from using obsolete hashing algorithms for passwords. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: I don't think you understand. MD5 itself is considered bad practice. Yes you should hash your passwords, but you should never use MD5 for this since it is now insecure.

Answer (score 0):

**password "correct" is weak - so hacker can use dictionary-bruteforce and find it quickly**

If your server is configured in wrong way and/or have som additional software (with bugs) hacker can use it to get access to files on your server via browser.

I assume that **you question is theoretical** and you aware that it is not good to store your users password explicite - in case when hacker get them with users emails then he can make many "bad things" because I think many users use their email password everywhere... So using `bcrypt` is good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a secure login.  And not just because of your choice of passwords.

You are right that in order to know what you were doing the hacker would have to get into the server and see the code.

However this is security through obscurity.  And is not effective.

You want to practice layers in your security.  You should assume that the hacker has access to your source code.  You should prevent them from getting into your page even with knowing the code.

After all, how sure are you that your server won't get hacked or the source code that you put on Github doesn't get out.  Or maybe an intern misconfigures the server and for Apache stops processing the php and just outputs the raw code.  You want your page to secure even with all of these things happening.

Please keep in mind that PHP has a [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function that can be used to check passwords.  And a [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function that will update the algorithm being used to help remain secure.

You shouldn't be doing plaintext comparisons of passwords in your code.  You should make it so that you are not able tell what the password is that the information doesn't get out.